# PyQt Calendar with only year/month view

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

In Qt Designer, the QDateTimeEdit has the option for a calendar view. By setting the display format, I am able to only display month/year.  However, when the user clicks on the view, it automatically makes a daily calendar show up. Is there a way to make it so only a month/year calendar is displayed?

To visually explain, the Windows calendar has the same initial view as the Qt calendar, but when I click the year, it switches to a month view:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that's a windows calendar's behavior, your should try using another Look n' Feel and check if it pleased you. Also, What do you want exactly? Do you want perhaps a spinbox with the years?

Comment: I want the second view, where the user clicks on the month.  I dont want to see days at all

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the `QDateEdit` widget, setting its `displayFormat` attribute to `MM/yyyy` and `currentSection` to `QDateTimeEdit.MonthSection` for instance.

Note that you can ask this widget to display a calendar when editing the value (`self.setCalendarPopup(True`)). By definition the calendar will display days, months and years.

Comment: I put this:self.dtMes.Section = QDateEdit.MonthSection but I can't to change like the second view of the main question