# QdateEdit display only mponths

Tags: python, datetime, calendar, pyqt5

I would like to obtain a calendar displaing only years and months.
In this link [PyQt Calendar with only year/month view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333793/pyqt-calendar-with-only-year-month-view) there is what I would like to obtain. I tried the solution but can't obtain the figure on the right (year/month) and what I get always opens the daily calendar

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit()
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 40, 110, 23))
        self.dateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")

        self.dateEdit.dateChanged.connect(self.onDateChanged)
        self.dateEdit.show()
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.dateEdit.setDisplayFormat(_translate("MyWindow", "MM/yyyy"))

    def onDateChanged(self, qDate):

        print('{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(qDate.day(), qDate.month(), qDate.year()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is what I would like to obtain:
[image: This is what I would like to obtain]

Comment: see the new edit of the question

Comment: @saceti it's not possible with the default behavior, and you need to create a custom widget on your own. The post you linked doesn't provide a solution for that, only a partial answer.

Comment: @musicamente thank you. Its strange none ever thought to build an official widget. Dreams

Comment: Well, while I can understand the need, you have to consider that a *major* toolkit has to evaluate the depth and needs of an implementation: is that really a *common* need? does a "general" implementation provide such basic features that are common to everybody that need such a widget? From my point of view, there are very *few* cases for which such widget would be actually needed, and, considering the ramifications of developing such a subclass, it wouldn't be worth it: such feature could be developed in *very* different ways, and creating a dedicated widget isn't that important.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: it *could* be useful, but its implementations can be very different, and you should consider the correct balance from the point of view of a *huge* toolkit as Qt is: they have *priorities*, and a widget like this is not one of them, considering the many ways it could be implemented and the many possible ways that should be considered in implementing a "general" class that could be valid for any of them.

Comment: @musicamente Sorry mate, I was jocking. My SW background has taught me that if you want gadgets that only serve you, you hit your head or give up. I gave up